# Не срабатывает jquery получение id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь получить id элемента, вроде элементарная процедура, но не находит ничего (undefined).
Код:

```js
function reserve() {
  alert(this.id);
};
```

```html
<a id="qweqwe" onclick="reserve();" href="#openModal2">тратата</a>
```

Так то же не срабатывает:

```
alert($(this).attr('id'));
```

jQuery подключен

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: `alert($('#qweqwe'));` что возвращает?

Comment: [object Object]

Comment: почему ты решил что тут `function reserve() {
  alert(this.id);  
 };` должен вывестись id элемента?

Comment: родителя таким образом получает alert($(this).parent());
id не должен?

Comment: давай с начала, ты знаешь, что есть `this` в контексте функции?) Почему ты решил, что оно указывает на элемент?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем примере:

```
function reserve() {
   alert(this.id);
};
```

`this` будет объектом `window`. Чтобы получить текущий элемент по которому вы кликнули, нужно на событие `onclick="reserve(**this**);"` передать `this`.

И тогда:

```
function reserve(element) {
    alert(element.id);
};
```

Вернет вам идентификатор.

Полный код примера:

```js
function reserve(element) {
  alert(element.id);
};
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<a id="qweqwe" onclick="reserve(this);" href="#openModal2">тратата</a>
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, так работает)
А как получить в таком случае id родителя этой ссылки?

Comment: можно подняться наверх, `element.parentNode.id`